# ¿Cómo hacer una lista para poder elegir, y que se abra un menú en Python?

Tags: python

He estado viendo las funciones de Python (variables, operaciones, operadores logicos, def, if, etc), Sé que esta pregunta puede ser muy básica pero, quiero hacer un menú desplegable.

Ejemplo:

```
1) Herramientas       3) Temperatura
2) Calculadora        4) Mas...

-Selecciona algo :
```

No quiero que me hagan "la tarea", si no dónde puedo aprender eso o qué es eso y si me pudieran explicar mucho mejor.

Comment: Hola @Snoop13. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Pensabas utilizar una lista de algún tipo particular o simplemente mostrar en consola el texto de algunas opciones preestablecidas y leer lo que ingrese el usuario?

Comment: Gracias Mariano, mira te explico quiero hacer que el usuario al seleccionar 1 se le abra "herramientas" y ahi otras opciones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una opción sencilla de implementarlo es imprimiendo el texto del menú en pantalla y leyendo lo que ingresa el usuario de esta forma:

```python
# Imprimimos el menú en pantalla
print("""
    1) Herramientas       3) Temperatura
    2) Calculadora        4) Mas...
    """)

# Leemos lo que ingresa el usuario
eligio=input("-Selecciona algo :")

# Según lo que ingresó, código diferente
if eligio=="1":
    print("Listamos otras herramientas")
elif eligio=="2":
    x = 3
    y = 5
    print("x * y = ", x * y)
elif eligio=="3":
    print("Creo que hace frío")
elif eligio=="4":
    print("otra opción")
else:
    print("Opción no válida")
```

Podrías llamar a funciones para cada elección (Herramientas, Calculadora, etc.), que te permitirán ordenar mejor el código.

Luego, para extenderlo, podrías poner este menú dentro de un bucle `while`, de modo que no salga del programa hasta que ingrese `x`, `salir`, o similar.

---

Nota: si estás en Python 2, hay que usar `raw_input()` en vez de `input()`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo